# Leak on iPad that I don't understand

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, ipad

I've got a leak in my application and I do not know why. Maybe I've got all memory managment thing wrong. In my code I've got  UIViewController object which have ivar TelephoneValidator *validator

TelephoneValidator is TelephoneValidator : NSObject

So in my initialization function of UIViewController object (initWithFieldData) I've got:

```
-(id) initWithFieldData: (NSMutableDictionary*) fieldData
{
...
     validatorOptions     = [fieldData objectForKey:@"fieldValidator"];
...
}
```

Now in my viewDidLoad I've got:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
if (![validatorOptions respondsToSelector:@selector(isEqualToString:)]) {

          validator = [[TelephoneValidator alloc] initWithOptions: validatorOptions];
     }
     else {
          validator = nil;
     }
...
}
```

Basicly if my validatorOptions isn't NSString the validator ivar became TelephoneValidator instance.

In my dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {

     if(validator != nil)
     {
          [validator release];
          validator = nil;
     }
...
[super dealloc];
    }
```

I've checked a couple of times if dealloc works, and it is. After calling dealloc the validator is released (calling any method on validator after [validator release] gets me exception).

And yet in Instruments it is telling me that TelephoneValidator is leaked. And after double clicking in Instruments the line of code that is highlited is:

```
validator = [[TelephoneValidator alloc] initWithOptions: validatorOptions];
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is my header information of UIViewController:

```
@interface GenericViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate>{

UIImage *backgroundImage;
NSString *step; // na ktorym kroku jestesmy
id <GenericControllerDelegate> delegate; //delegata z ktorej bedziemy pobierali dane 
UITextField *textField;
NSString *fieldName; //nazwa pola (potrzebujemy zeby zapisac do modelu odpowiedni tekst
UILabel  *textLabel;
UILabel *stepsLabel;
UILabel *prefixTextLabel;

NSString *fieldPlaceholder;
NSString *textLabelText;
NSString *textLabelTextPl; //w jezyku polskim 
NSString *prefixTextLabelText; //w jezyku eng
NSString *prefixTextLabelTextPl; //w jezyku polskim prefix

NSString *fieldRequired;
NSString *keyboardType;
NSString *capitalizeType;

UIButton *button; //forward button
UIButton *button2;  //backward button

//to bedzie do przerobienia bo bedziemy mieli tablicje walidatorow a nie jeden walidator
NSString *validatorType;

//maksymalna dlugosc pola
int maxLengthOfTextField;

NSArray* validatorOptions;

TelephoneValidator *validator; 

//patientModel
PatientData *patientModel;
```

}

TelephoneValidator header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MAOTranslate.h"

@interface TelephoneValidator : NSObject {


    //opcje walidacyjne
    NSString *phonePrefix;
    NSString *phonePostfix;
    int       phoneLength;
    NSString *message;
    NSString *messagePl;

    UIAlertView *alertView;
}

-(id) initWithOptions:(NSArray *) optionsArray;

-(void) displayMessage;
-(BOOL) validate: (NSString *) phoneNumber;


@end
```

TelephoneValidator class:

```
#import "TelephoneValidator.h"


@implementation TelephoneValidator
//@synthesize phoneNumber;

-(id) initWithOptions:(NSArray *) optionsArray;
{
    if(self = [[TelephoneValidator alloc] init])
    {
        phonePrefix = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        phonePostfix = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:1];
        phoneLength = [[optionsArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        message = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:3];
        messagePl = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:4];
    }
    else {
        self = nil;
    }

    return self;


}

//wyswietlamy wiadomosc
-(void) displayMessage
{
    NSString *displayMsg;
    if ([[MAOTranslate getLanguage] isEqualToString:@"pl"]) {
        displayMsg = messagePl;
    }
    else {
        displayMsg = message;
    }

    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:displayMsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}

-(BOOL) validate: (NSString *) phoneNumber
{


    //dlugosc
    if ([phoneNumber length] != phoneLength) {
        NSLog(@"zla dlugosc");
        return NO;
    }


    NSLog(@"tutaj");
    //sprawdzamy prefix     
    if ([phonePrefix length]!= 0) {     
        NSLog(@"w srodku ifa");
        if ([phoneNumber compare:phonePrefix options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [phonePrefix length])] != 0) {
            NSLog(@"zly prefix");
            [self displayMessage];
            return NO;
        }
    }

    //sprawdzamy postfix
    if([phonePostfix length] != 0)
    {
        if ([phoneNumber compare:phonePostfix options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange([phoneNumber length]-[phonePostfix length], [phonePostfix length])] != 0) {
            NSLog(@"zly postfix");
            [self displayMessage];
            return NO;
        }
    }


    //sprawdzamy czy string jest numeryczny

    NSCharacterSet *alphaNums = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];  
    NSCharacterSet *inStringSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:phoneNumber];  

    if (![alphaNums isSupersetOfSet:inStringSet]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"zly format ");
        [self displayMessage];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES; //zwalidowany poprawnie
}

-(void) dealloc
{   

    [alertView release];
    alertView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong in these parts of the code, must be somewhere else.

Comment: I did think so too, that nothingis wrong here. Nevertheless Instruments keep insisting that the leak is here. My application work in Navigation Controller so I'm pushing my UIViewController and that's when I've got this leak. Where to begin searching my code? It's the only place where I use this object (TelephoneValidator).

Comment: does `[[TelephoneValidator alloc] initWithOptions: validatorOptions]` retain anything?  Post that code.

Comment: Done, I've updated main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See These both lines

```
validator = [[TelephoneValidator alloc] initWithOptions: validatorOptions];
```

and inside initWithOptions

```
if(self = [[TelephoneValidator alloc] init])
```

You are allocing twice the validator, so there is a leak.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [super dealloc] at the end of the dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that instruments is pointing to `validatorOptions` as the source of the leak? Is it a retained property being released at dealloc or not? I can't say for sure, the code you posted is not enough to arrive to a conclusion.

Also, as willcodejavaforfood says, you must always call `[super dealloc];` at the end of your dealloc method. No code must come after it.

Edit:

I'm back. But Bruno Domingues got it right already, you are allocating twice, in which case, the first one leaks. You should change your `-initWithOptions:` code to:

```
-(id) initWithOptions:(NSArray *) optionsArray;
{
    if((self = [super init])){
    // ... rest of code is fine
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I've moved [super dealloc] to botttom of everything. Maybe I can't use Instruments right. What I am doing is: 1. getting to the point in my app where the leak occurs. 2.On Leaked Blocks tab I've got TelephoneValidator (so it's not validatorOptions), then some address then number of bytes leaked, then my app name (as responsible library) then responsible frame is name of my UIViewController. Now I double click on TelephoneValidator text and it gets me right into the code which I've posted. I could provide more code, but what exactly do you mean by statint that it isn't enough?

Comment: You're using Instruments fine. I meant it isn't enough to conclude that `validatorOptions` is leaking. Have you checked if it is indeed the object that is leaking? How did you declare and where do you release `validatorOptions`?

Comment: validatorOptions is another ivar and it is setted in initilizier: validatorOptions = [fieldData objectForKey:@"fieldValidator"] at first I've got no release on validatorOptions but after your comment I've updated my dealloc and there is now  [validatorOptions release]; But the leak occurs when I create UIViewController (after viewDidLoad), not when I'm poping it back. I'm little confused, why there is a leak when you've just created an object?

Comment: If validatorOptions is just an ivar (not a retained property) then you should add a `retain` to it when it is assigned in init. `objectForKey` returns an autoreleased object. Add a `retain` in init and keep the `release` in dealloc. Is `validator` also just an ivar and not a retained property?

Comment: ivar = instance variable right? I will update my original post with revelant header information.

Comment: Comments are in polish (my native language) so ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to look at this in a couple of hours, I need to run home now. :)